# How to check equality of each row/column in matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a `char Board[3][3]` matrix. I am trying to check, whether the elements in each row/column are equal. ie. `Board[0][0] == Board[0][1] == Board[0][2]`, and so on for the other rows and columns.

This is for checking for a win in a tic-tac-toe game, so obviously, writing all the possible combinations is very 'inefficient'.

Is there any shorter way to do this?

Comment: Just write it down and you have the fasted code possible.

Comment: @DieterLücking I think he isn't looking for "efficient" in terms of performance, but instead in terms of code length

Comment: 2 `for` loops to check for row and column winning condition and 2 explicit checks for diagonals should do.

Comment: If each element possible values is either 0 or 1 then you can check this with the sum; e.g.: `Board[0][0] + Board[0][1] + Board[0][2]`. Sum of 0 or 3 means same, otherwise means differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a helper function to check that three items on a specific line are equal to each other. A line can be defined by an `(row, col)` position on the edge of the board and a pair of "deltas" `(dr, dc)` defining the "step" we need to take to get to the next square on the specific line:

```
bool check(char b[3][3], int row, int col, int dr, int dc) {
    return b[row][col] == b[row+dr][col+dc]
        && b[row][col] == b[row+2*dr][col+2*dc];
}
```

To check if there is a win on the board you can check all eight winning lines:

```
bool hasWin = check(0, 0, 0, 1) // First horizontal line
           || check(1, 0, 0, 1) // Second horizontal line
           || check(2, 0, 0, 1) // Third horizontal line
           || check(0, 0, 1, 0) // First vertical line
           || check(0, 1, 1, 0) // Second vertical line
           || check(0, 2, 1, 0) // Third vertical line
           || check(0, 0, 1, 1) // First diagonal
           || check(0, 2, 1, -1); // Second diagonal
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in a sense of

```
i = 1;
while(i<Board_size && Board[0][i-1] == Board[0][i])
{
    i++;
}
if (i<Board_size) not equal;
```

?

Not very efficient either, but simple.

edit, the whole board:

```
int i;
for (int j=0;j<Board_size;j++)
{
    i = 1;
    while(i<Board_size && Board[j][i-1] == Board[j][i])
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (i<Board_size) line j not equal;

    i = 1;
    while(i<Board_size && Board[i-1][j] == Board[i][j])
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (i<Board_size) column j not equal;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work.  This doesnt check diagonals, columns, or 2 of the 3 rows

Comment: That sure looks like a for-statement to me.

Comment: He asked for elements in each row/column, nothing about diagonals, but yeah, I should've assumed that by the tic-tac-toe thing. And it's just part of a code for 1 line. Wrap it in for-loop and do it once for rows, once for columns. I thought he just wants how can the comparison be made by itself, not how to check the whole board.


And yeah, it could be done as for-loop instead, with dropping flag by break;